# foreach statement to get the values from an array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

This is a short example of an array that I am working with.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Name] => somename [Attributes] => Array ( [Body] => somebody 
[Region] => someregion [State] => somestate [Url] => someurl [Date] => somedate [Tz] => 
sometz [Title] => sometitle [City] => somecity ) ) [1] => Array ( [Name] => somename1 
[Attributes] => Array ( [Body] => somebody1 [Region] => someregion1 [State] => somestate1 
[Url] => someurl1 [Date] => somedate1 [Tz] => sometz1 [Title] => sometitle1 [City] => 
somecity1 ) ) )
```

I just need help with the foreach statement to get the values of each array.

Any example of sorting these arrays based on the date would be appreciated too.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to look at php documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

In this case you just want to do:

```
foreach (your_array_name as $value)
    //do something with $value
```

Comment: I was on that page before I asked the question, and tried some examples.  Just wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: Thanks,  I made a stupid mistake.  I was adding the code into one file and then checking a duplicate I had made.  No wonder I couldn't get it to work.  `foreach ($rest as $value)
 {
 echo $value['Name'];
 etc.etc..
 }`

Answer (score 2):

A solution would be to use two nested [foreach()](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
  foreach($value as $v){
    echo $v;
  }
}
```

Finally, in order to sort your array, you can use either [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), or [cmp()](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php).
Don't forget to **use the same format** for your date (ideally ISO 8601) so you can sort them easily.

Answer (score 1):

Use the technique of multi sort http://in.php.net/array_multisort

```
$array1 = array(0 => array('name' => somename1, 'Attributes' => array('Body' => somebody,
                'Region' => someregion, 'State' => somestate, 'Url' => someurl, 'Date' => '26-02-2011', 'Tz' =>
                sometz, 'Title' => sometitle, 'City' => somecity)),
        1 => array('name' => somename2, 'Attributes' => array('Body' => somebody,
                'Region' => someregion, 'State' => somestate, 'Url' => someurl, 'Date' => '25-02-2011', 'Tz' =>
                sometz, 'Title' => sometitle, 'City' => somecity)));

    foreach ($array1 as $index => $inner_arr) {
        $attr = $inner_arr['Attributes'];
        foreach ($attr as $key => $value) {
            $date_arr[$index] = strtotime($attr['Date']);
        }
    } 
//for multisort give date array as the array accoring to which the data to be sorted. 
//We are dumping date into array and trying to sort data according tot he date array sorted.

    array_multisort($date_arr,$array1);

    //after sorting loop thru data
    foreach ($array1 as $inner_arr) {
        echo "name:". $inner_arr['name'];
        foreach ($inner_arr['Attributes'] as $key => $value) {
            echo "<br>$key: $value";

        }
        echo '<hr>';
    }
```